# how to update db with private helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to rails, and I think i found my problem but I'm not sure if this is the case

```
def additional_info
 @user = User.find params[:id]
end


def update
 @user =  User.find(params[:id])
 if @user.update(user_addinfo)
     render user_path
 else
     render action: 'additional_info'
 end
end


def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end


def user_addinfo
  params.require(:user).permit(:years_business, :years_relationships, :years_careers, :years_lifeoutlook)
end
end
```

A user suggested that i change the

```
if @user.update(user_addinfo) to -> if@user.update!(user_addinfo)
```

the result was an error page saying my password is too short! I went back reread Michael Hartl's guide and rails api on the params. section and i believe this is causing an issue? I've tried changing to

```
params.permit(:years_business, :years_relationships, :years_careers, :years_lifeoutlook)
```

only and it still gives a password too short error.... what am i doing wrong? or am i totally misunderstanding the params?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a [length validation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length) in the `User` model that checks for the length of the given password.

Open the `app/models/user.rb` file and look for a line like this:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 4 }
```

or:

```
validates_length_of :password
```

Comment: i found the line, but the attributes im trying to update are not password related at all(just regular data). Do i have to modify or change something?

Comment: The error is clearly stating that a short password was passed. Delete the validation and see if it works.